# Connection failed error for client connected to server over wifi (TCP socket program in c)

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, tcpip, sockets

Requirement : Need to send and receive message from two devices connected over wifi using TCP socket programming in c.

Receiving connection failed for client socket. I am able to connect same client through USB using same socket programs in c. Following are config details.

Both IPs are in same subnet.

System : Ubuntu 14.04
Firewall : disabled

```
abhishek@vidyut:~$sudo ufw status
Status: inactive
```

Client side config details :

```
root@swi-mdm9x15:~# ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 2A:DF:53:54:15:A2  
          inet addr:192.168.17.1  Bcast:192.168.17.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:125 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:125 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:8851 (8.6 KiB)  TX bytes:8851 (8.6 KiB)

rmnet0    Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  
          inet addr:100.81.198.219  Mask:255.255.255.248
          inet6 addr: fe80::a5e8:cd72:5a0:d0ab/64 Scope:Link
          UP RUNNING  MTU:1430  Metric:1
          RX packets:29 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:38 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:3394 (3.3 KiB)  TX bytes:3912 (3.8 KiB)

usb0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr BE:B3:25:7B:2A:D1  
          inet addr:192.168.2.2  Bcast:192.168.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::bcb3:25ff:fe7b:2ad1/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:185 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:87 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:19533 (19.0 KiB)  TX bytes:11725 (11.4 KiB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 7C:DD:90:CB:FE:1D  
          inet addr:**192.168.1.4**  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::7edd:90ff:fecb:fe1d/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:12 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:2004 (1.9 KiB)

root@swi-mdm9x15:~#
```

==============================================================

Server side config details :

```
abhishek@vidyut:~$ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr d0:bf:9c:05:bd:65  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:23702 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:23702 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
          RX bytes:1997818 (1.9 MB)  TX bytes:1997818 (1.9 MB)

usb0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 02:a5:2c:72:e1:95  
          inet addr:192.168.2.3  Bcast:192.168.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::a5:2cff:fe72:e195/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:520 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:652 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:286008 (286.0 KB)  TX bytes:66095 (66.0 KB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 74:29:af:18:6a:e9  
          inet addr:**192.168.1.32**  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::7629:afff:fe18:6ae9/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:137395 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:81588 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:107297162 (107.2 MB)  TX bytes:15416536 (15.4 MB)
```

Comment: To test if the error is in your internet setup or your C program, use nc/netcat/socat to  send and receive messages from those devices. If that works, the error is in the C program. If it doesn't work, run `tcpdump -ni wlan0` on both machines, and see what happens to your packets. Also try `ping`.

Comment: hi  dirkt , I tried to send message using ncat. Both sysytems are able to communicate between each other when system with wifi IP 192.168.1.41 used as serer and system with wifi IP 192.168.1.32 as client. Same has been verified with C program . But unable to communicate between each other when server and client are interchanged. Pls suggest.

Comment: Guess: You have some NAT somewhere in between the machines. Look at all machines between server and client, look at `iptables` contents on all of them. Debug with `tcpdump -ni eth0` etc. on each interesting network interface, so you can see how far your packets get.

Comment: as per IP tables , no constraints on both sides :